# How to print the first 30 lines of a html, by using urllib?

Tags: python, urllib

I trying to print out the first 30 lines of a html page, I tried to solve this problem as if to print out the first 30 lines of a .txt document.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()

count=0
xx=html.decode()
for line in xx:
    count=count+1
    if count<30:
        print(line)
```

However, the program runs and prints out the html in letters one by one (instead of in lines). The results are printed out one letter each line.

Not sure how to solve this problem! Thanks!!

Comment: Probably you have a big string, try using xx=xx.split('\n') before

Comment: What do you mean when you say "line", because this is not something that is defined in HTML. Do you want the first thirty lines of source code, or first thirty lines of the rendered page (what you see on the screen when you load the link in a browser)?

Comment: try `html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).readlines()` to split `bytes` into `list`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `read()`, try using `readlines()` and replace the code snippet as following:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).readlines()

count=0

for line in html:
    count=count+1
    if count<30:
        print(line)
```

I hope, it helps!